# Why does python return a TypeError?

Tags: python

*I have to make a program that uses the quadratic formula with values for a, b and c supplied by the user.*

**Here's the code:**

```
import math
from math import sqrt
from math import pow

#input values
a = input('Value for a: ')
b = input('Value for b: ')
c = input('Value for c: ')

#calculate the discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

if d < 0:
    d *= -1
else:
    d=d

#Get two solutions
sol1 = (-b - math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
sol2 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

#print two solutions
print("El valor de x1 es:"), sol1

print("El valor de x2 es:"), sol2
```

**Here's the result:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valeriamansilla/PycharmProjects/untitled/Quadratic          Formular.py", line 11, in <module>
    d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: python 3: `input` returns a str not an integer. Convert the values and you're good.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you convert the values?

Comment: @V.Mjo You can check type of a with print(type(a)) then you will get 'str' instead of 'int'.

If you want to convert str to int, just use int(a) or float(a) if you want to make it float.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 1):

`input` gets the input from the user as a string. You need to get integer values so you can perform mathematical operations on them:

```
a = int(input('Value for a: '))
b = int(input('Value for b: '))
c = int(input('Value for c: '))
```